# bootstrap 4 - two column layout with second column to show details in mobile view

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <h1>Servers</h1>
        <ul>
          <li>server 1</li>
          <li>server 2</li>
          <li>server 3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <h1>server details</h1>
        <p class="lead">server 1 is online.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>
```

I want to create a bootstrap 2 column layout. the first column to have list of servers. and second column to have server details. when no server is selected - it shows number of servers online, etc.

On mobile view - I don't want to have the column 2 below column column 1. But I want to have column 2 hidden or show on (right to left) swipe. column 2 hidden also ok.
On mobile view - the list of servers is shown and when the user clicks on one server, the view should move to column2 showing the server details. I can have the details loaded/rendered on column 2.

I have columns as following classes:

column1 - col-md-6, col-sm-12

column2 - col-md-6, col-sm-12

could someone guide me to right direction please?

Comment: please  provide me html  css code

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

Comment: added the html code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create that from css. By using media queries
Dive both div with different IDs, or class names.
And,

```
@media only screen and (max-width:300px){
  .column2{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

And this will hide the div, when the device screen width is below 300px